# Duplicate file reference in project.pbxproj

Tags: iphone, xcode, merge

Recently my development team grew and we started working on branches in SVN.
if we add files to the project in two branches, and merge them afterwards, I can't open the project from xcode anymore. 
I did some investigation and found out that the project file uses hash for each node in the source tree, and when two files are added on a different branches they might have the same hash. It happens almost every merge we are doing.

How can I solve the issue?

Comment: why aren't you using another svn program ? Like Source Off Site? It's safe and reliable once you get it started and going.

Comment: it is not related to the SVN program, after successful merge the file has duplicates entries

Comment: It's really hard to answer this without just saying "don't use svn branches".  However, if you're stuck with them that doesn't help much. Perhaps exclude the .xcodeproj from source control on the subordinate branches and keep one good copy on trunk, or some other branch that makes sense.  You might also think about using git-svn.  This allows each developer to have a local copy of the whole repository,make local commits at will, and only merge upstream commits when they wish.  Might make for a more complicated, but less painful workflow.

Comment: the problem is not really related to any source control. when one developer adds a file to the project, xcode gives it a hash. if another developer adds another file, it might have the same hash. when you has lots of files, the probability is high because xcode hash alg is not good.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, You have to resolve pbxproj file manually. Or, You can use one of [these build systems](http://blog.bengarney.com/2012/08/26/some-thoughts-on-build-systems/). (I recommand CMake beacuase it supports XCode)

Comment: I'm not sure how CMake will resolve the issue, it still read the project file. Right?